# Why Iterator suddenly printed the map elements in reverse order?

Tags: java, json

Suppose we have a block of JAVA code which is iterating through the JSON file.

**JAVAfile**

```
        // getting phoneNumbers
        JSONArray ja = (JSONArray) jo.get("phoneNumbers");//jo is the JSONObject of the given JSON 
        //Iterating through phonenumbers 
        Iterator itr2 = ja.iterator();
          
        while (itr2.hasNext()) 
        {
            Iterator<Map.Entry>itr1 = ((Map)itr2.next()).entrySet().iterator();
            while (itr1.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry pair = itr1.next();
                System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " : " + pair.getValue());
            }
        }
```

**JSONfile**

```
{
    "firstName": "Souvik",
    "lastName": "Dey",
    "address": {
        "streetAddress": "D P Rd",
        "city": "Barasat",
        "state": "WB",
        "postalCode": 700126
    },
    "age": 23,
    "phoneNumbers": [
        {
            "type": "personal",
            "number": "#######23"
        },
        {
            "type": "office",
            "number": "########"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Question**

Why am I getting this:

---

**Output**

> number : #######23
> type : personal
> number : ########
> type : office

**Expectations**

> type : personal
> number : #######23
> type : office
> number : ########

---

Comment: Hello. Please [ask one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222735). BTW most JSON libraries are open source so you can take a look at any method and see how it works. Regarding order of `type` vs `number` JSONObject doesn't guarantee order of keys (just like HashMap).

Comment: How about adding the code that explains how `itr2` is initialized, as well as explaining what `ja` is? I'm guessing JSONArray but... why don't you parse the whole annonymous json (`Map.Entry pair` in your case) into a class that has `String type; String number;` members and then print `type` followed by `number` explicitly instead of relying on whatever the JSONArray decided is key/value ?

Comment: The order of the map-elements depend on the implementation of the map. Maintaining the order of the JSON is not guaranteed. If you require a consistent order for the keys, you should change the implementation to either parse each phoneNumber as an object or explicitly extract each field from the maps you iterate over

Comment: I see the comments, problem is with the "Iteration", why suddenly number came before type? @Shark

Comment: To tie in with @ODDminus1 answer - the order of the map-elements depands on the Map's implementation. The `Map.Entry pair` decided one of the is going to be Key and the other is going to be Value. It's implementation dependant, I cant (don't) know why, but you should either parse the entry into a class, or get the JSONObject and fetch the `type` and `number` yourself instead of expecting the order to be preserved, since JSON is unordered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map elements in JSON are not regarded as ordered data.  It comes out in a different order for reasons similar to the ordering of a HashMap's contents.  You shouldn't expect a HashMap to iterate in the same order that you put content into it, and the same is true for mapped content from a JSON source.

If you want to preserve the order of mapped data in JSON, then you should transform the mapped data to an array and store that in JSON.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use the equivalent of a pull-parser, such as GSON JsonReader, which would access elements in the same order they are read from the document.

Comment: Thanks, so is it just a coincident that, iterator is printing in reverse order? I tried more(3,4,5) elements inside that map and still it printed in reverse order. @phatfingers

Comment: Yes, it is just a coincidence.

Comment: @desouvik Although not guaranteed to be, the ordering is influenced by the hash value of each key.  So, it will appear consistent for multiple sets but it's not safe to rely on that consistency across different versions of Java.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Jackson to parse the JSON file into a `JsonNode`, grab the `phoneNumbers` field and iterate through the nodes. Jackson uses a `LinkedHashMap` under the hood, so they original order of they keys should be preserved.

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.exc.StreamReadException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.*;

public class JsonReaderExample {
    private static ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ClassLoader classLoader = JsonReaderExample.class.getClassLoader();
            InputStream inputStream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("input.json");
            JsonNode person = objectMapper.readTree(inputStream);
            JsonNode phoneNumbers = person.get("phoneNumbers");
            if (phoneNumbers.isArray()) {
                for (final JsonNode phoneNumber : phoneNumbers) {
                    Iterator<Entry<String, JsonNode>> it = phoneNumber.fields();
                    while (it.hasNext()) {
                        Entry<String, JsonNode> entry = it.next();
                        System.out.printf("%s: %s%n", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (StreamReadException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (DatabindException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Your safest bet would be to deserialize the JSON as a POJO. You can use Jackson to read the JSON data and parse it into a `Person`.

```java
import java.io.*;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.exc.StreamReadException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.*;

public class JsonReaderExample {
    private static ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ClassLoader classLoader = JsonReaderExample.class.getClassLoader();
            InputStream inputStream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("input.json");
            Person person = objectMapper.readValue(inputStream, Person.class);

            for (PhoneNumber phoneNumber : person.phoneNumbers) {
                System.out.printf("type: %s%n", phoneNumber.type);
                System.out.printf("number: %s%n", phoneNumber.number);
            }
        } catch (StreamReadException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (DatabindException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static class Person {
        public String firstName;
        public String lastName;
        public Address address;
        public int age;
        public PhoneNumber[] phoneNumbers;
    }

    private static class PhoneNumber {
        public String type;
        public String number;
    }

    private static class Address {
        public String streetAddress;
        public String city;
        public String state;
        public int postalCode;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
type: personal
number: #######23
type: office
number: ########
```